# Select the right XMLelement

Tags: data, filtering, web-access, xml

I scrape data from a public website about houses for rent. All pages have the same structure. But the pages can differ in the amount of information.

Below I give two examples:

#### page/house 1:

```
test = Cases[
  fundafiles1, 
  XMLElement["dl", {"class" -> "object-kenmerken-list"}, __], 
  ∞
];

Cases[test, {XMLElement[ "dt", {}, {"number rooms"}], ___}, ∞]
```

The output is:

> ```
> { { XMLElement["dt", {}, {"number rooms"}],    
>     XMLElement["dd", {}, {"4 rooms (3 slepingrooms)"}],    
>     XMLElement["dt", {}, {"number floors"}],    
>     XMLElement["dd", {}, {"2 floors"}],    
>     XMLElement["dt", {}, {"services"}],    
>     XMLElement["dd", {}, {"Mechanische ventilatie, TV kabel, jacuzzi en schuifpui"}]
>   }
> }
> ```

#### for page/house 2 I use the same script:

```
test = Cases[
  fundafiles1, 
  XMLElement["dl", {"class" -> "object-kenmerken-list"}, __], 
  ∞
];

Cases[test, {XMLElement["dt", {}, {"number rooms"}], ___}, ∞]
```

but now the output is:

> ```
> { { XMLElement["dt", {}, {"Number rooms"}],    
>     XMLElement["dd", {}, {"2 rooms (1 slepingroom)"}],    
>     XMLElement["dt", {}, {"Number bathrooms"}],    
>     XMLElement["dd", {}, {"1 bathroom en 1  toilet"}],   
>     XMLElement["dt", {}, {"bathroomservices"}],    
>     XMLElement["dd", {}, {"Douche"}],    
>     XMLElement["dt", {}, {"number floors"}],   
>     XMLElement["dd", {}, {"1 floor"}],    
>     XMLElement["dt", {}, {"located"}],    
>     XMLElement["dd", {}, {"2e floor"}],   
>     XMLElement["dt", {}, {"services"}],    
>     XMLElement["dd", {}, {"elevator"}]
>   }
> }
> ```

Because the number of attritutes can differ, the attributes don't have their own position. I want to collect the data and put them in a new table for further analysis.

For example: I want to select `"Number rooms"` end get as answer a number. Who has a suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide a small (made up) xml example to work with which exhibits your problems? I'm also not sure what is the desired result.

Comment: Are `"Number rooms"` and `"number of rooms"` both supposed to match your search pattern?

Comment: your are right, it must be 'number rooms'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess as to what you want:

```
in1 = {{XMLElement["dt", {}, {"number of rooms"}], 
    XMLElement["dd", {}, {"4 rooms (3 slepingrooms)"}], 
    XMLElement["dt", {}, {"number floors"}], XMLElement["dd", {}, {"2 floors"}], 
    XMLElement["dt", {}, {"services"}], 
    XMLElement[
     "dd", {}, {"Mechanische ventilatie, TV kabel, jacuzzi en schuifpui"}]}};

in2 = {{XMLElement["dt", {}, {"Number rooms"}], 
    XMLElement["dd", {}, {"2 rooms (1 slepingroom)"}], 
    XMLElement["dt", {}, {"Number bathrooms"}], 
    XMLElement["dd", {}, {"1 bathroom en 1  toilet"}], 
    XMLElement["dt", {}, {"bathroomservices"}], XMLElement["dd", {}, {"Douche"}], 
    XMLElement["dt", {}, {"number floors"}], XMLElement["dd", {}, {"1 floor"}], 
    XMLElement["dt", {}, {"located"}], XMLElement["dd", {}, {"2e floor"}], 
    XMLElement["dt", {}, {"services"}], XMLElement["dd", {}, {"elevator"}]}};

target = StringMatchQ[#, "number*rooms", IgnoreCase -> True] &;

filter = Cases[{___, XMLElement["dt", {}, {_?target}], 
     XMLElement["dd", {}, {value_}], ___} :> value];

filter /@ {in1, in2}
```

> ```
> {{"4 rooms (3 slepingrooms)"}, {"2 rooms (1 slepingroom)"}}
> ```